# Share image painted on a larger graphics than the screen itself

Tags: codenameone

The code bellow will paint he component on the image graphics - but it will translate it - instead of fitting it to the size of the graphics.

```
int ratio = 2;
Image screenshotImage = Image.createImage(getWidth()* ratio,getHeight()* ratio);
c.revalidate();
c.setVisible(true);
c.paintComponent(screenshotImage.getGraphics(), true);
```

I cannot use the the image and just scale it because some of the content will be truncated.
Can the component paint itself on image graphics with specified size.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
c.setX(0);
c.setY(0);
c.setWidth(img.getWidth());
c.setHeight(img.getHeight());
if(c instanceof Container) {
   c.setShouldLayout(true);
   c.layoutContainer();
}
c.remove();
c.paintComponent(myImage.getGraphics(), true);
// add c back to it's parent container and revalidate
```

If the component is currently on a form you would want to undo all of that by calling revalidate on the parent form afterwards.

Comment: setShouldLayout is protected so I created new container class by overriding  and adding a method will all your code. Did not work.

Comment: Yeha I copied and pasted and setWidth/Height to 0. Fixed that now.

Comment: much better - it paints the component on the image - but clips only the screen visible - can we get it all ?

Comment: OK I neglected to mention the remove bit which I added in the sample. By having no parent the component won't try to clip or translate to parent coordinate space